# Chrome Version 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit), developer tool not launching

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

My Chrome automatically updated itself to Version 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit) today 10/14/15, and it looks like the developer tool is broken – it can not be launched.

I uninstalled Chrome latest, and installed Version 45, the developer tool is working fine. But then Chrome immediately upgrades itself to Version 46 again. 
I tried to stop the auto upgrade of Chrome by: defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0

that does not seem to have any effect – Chrome still tried to auto-upgrade itself.

Is there anyone else using Chrome latest and have the same issue?

Comment: Can you check if it is working with Chrome Canary https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html ?

Comment: Yes, I did check and it is working with canary

Comment: Same for me, the chrome version is Version 46.0.2490.71 m. Tried uninstallation but it does not help. Reported the issue to google.